# 'grunt serve' starts fine but never loads

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster, browser-sync

I just created a new application using JHipster on Windows.  I can run it just fine using "mvn spring-boot:run".  However, I would like to get auto-reloading of pages and so would like to use "grunt serve".  When I run it, it starts fine.  But when I go to "http://localhost:3000/" in Chrome it just sits there waiting for the server to connect.  I can go to http://localhost:3001/ just fine and see BrowserSync but there are not any servers listed under the "Current Connections" section.

Here is the out put I see after running "grunt serve":

```
C:\mydev\pmi>grunt serve
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "ngconstant:dev" (ngconstant) task
Creating module pmiApp at src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.constants.js...OK

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "browserSync:dev" (browserSync) task
[BS] [info] Proxying: http://localhost:8080
[BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.255.247.72:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.255.247.72:3001
 --------------------------------------
[BS] Watching files...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

I just never see anything in the browser (neither Chrome nor Firefox connect).

I saw another post suggesting that I delete my node-modules directory and reinstall use "npm install".  I did that and got the same result.

I've been looking at it for an hour and a half tonight.  Last night, something finally triggered and it started working.  But I'm getting the same problem tonight.  I don't know what finally got it working last night.  I had been having the same problem for an hour last night.

I'm stumped.

Comment: I have the same error, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh

I was under the mistaken assumption that 'grunt serve' did the same thing (only better) as "mvn spring-boot:run".   Not so.

"mvn spring-boot:run" runs the backend web server and handles the REST endpoints.

'grunt serve' handles the front end angularJS side of things.

Looking back at the documentation it is now obvious.

What a Noob.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one :).  I was having trouble with this as well.

Just to clarify.  You need to run both

'mvn spring-boot:run'

and

'grunt serve'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle you can run this:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

In my case the message bellow informs that you can access the spring application:
**> Building 85% > :bootRun**

After that you can run this:

```
grunt serve
```

The message *"Running "watch" task Waiting..."* will appear in the console, but 
the browser will open automatically and show the address bellow:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/
```